# Проблема со слайдером на iOS устройствах

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

На сайте cookeryschool.com.ua (сайт на вордпрессе) есть слайдер с курсами(сделан с помощью bx-slider), на разных по ширине экранах слайдер отображается по разному (4 в ряд, 3 в ряд, 2 в ряд и на смартфонах 1 в ряд). Как только заходишь на сайт с любого айфона и листаешь вниз к этому слайдеру, то слайдер отображается вот так:

[image: проблема]

Но если нажать на стрелку вправо или влево, то все становится на свои места:

Так должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данная проблема наблюдается только на яблочных смартфонах, на андроидах данного бага не обнаружено, подскажите как решить?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему ломается вёрстка, но так как я не вижу кода, советую использовать следующий код для слайдера:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slide {
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
  background: url(http://krolik74.kpeatop.com/hosting.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46y8zp0s/2/)

Comment: к сожалению не помогло.

Comment: Вы пробовали ?) `flex` работает в `safari`. Если не помогло значит проблема конкретно с айфоном, у меня на маке все рабоатет отлично.

Comment: Да, я добавил внешнему блоку эти свойства, я же говорю, что проблема только на смартфонах яблочных, на всех остальных устройствах норм.

Comment: Нужно не просто добавить, а и сделать как указано выше,  то есть задать ширину и высоту блокам слайдера. А на тестовом айфоне сафари давно обновляли?

Comment: У них указаны ширина и высота, просто немного другие, не знаю когда обновляли сафари, айфон не мой. Но такое проверяли на нескольких разных айфонах и баг везде тот же.